# Trying to edit multiple records at once, saveAll not working

Tags: cakephp

I'm saving multiple Widgets and associated WidgetsItems to a menu, which I have working fine.

The problem is, my edit function is not working. I understand that the data array structure needs to be as following, as it is what is saving my data properly in the first place:

> ```
> Array (
> [Widget] => Array
>     (
>         [23] => Array
>             (
>                 [title] => Cocktails
>                 [id] => 23
>                 [WidgetsItem] => Array
>                     (
>                         [147] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [item] => Martini: Noilly Pratt, Ginor Vodka
>                                 [price] => 24
>                                 [id] => 147
>                             )
>                         [148] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [item] => Negroni: Campari, Gin, Sweet Vermouth
>                                 [price] => 16
>                                 [id] => 148
>                             )
>                     )
>             )
> ```

using the following controller code:

```
foreach($this->data['Widget'] as $widgetKey => $widget) : 
                $widgetData = array(
                    'title' => $widget['title'],
                    'id' => $widget['id']
                );
                $saveableWidget = Set::insert($widget, 'Widget', $widgetData);
                if($this->Widget->saveAll($saveableWidget)) : $saveSuccess = true; endif;
            endforeach;
```

Which is copied and pasted from the initial save function, then modified a little for editing. Instead, it's creating new entries, not editing them. I know it's something to do with the IDs, but it's just not saving. What am I doing wrong?

Please help, I feel like I'm very close to a nearly finished product.

Thanks,

~harley

Comment: solved... edited the code above to work.

Comment: add it as the answer so people don't come to this question seeing "0 answers".  (glad you figured it out!)